# Trying to set a default mat-radio-button

Tags: html, angular

I attempting to set a default checked box (value 100) if no button has been selected by the user/ or if the user does not explicitly select a checkbox. Please see my current implementation:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <mat-radio-group #radioGroup="matRadioGroup" (change)="radioChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="queueManageBean.resReturn">
        <mat-radio-button
                    value="10" [checked]="10 == queueManageBean.resReturn">10</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="25" style="margin-left: 15px;"
                [checked]="25 == queueManageBean.resReturn">25</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="100" style="margin-left: 15px;"
                [checked]="100 == queueManageBean.resReturn">100</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="250" style="margin-left: 15px;"
                [checked]="250 == queueManageBean.resReturn">250</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="500" style="margin-left: 15px;"
                [checked]="500 == queueManageBean.resReturn">500</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

The queueManageBean.resReturn is retrieved from ts

```
queueManageBean = new queueManageBean;
resReturn:number;
this.queueManageBean.resReturn = this.resReturn;
```

Even if I explicitly set value 100 to 'true', it still is not the default value. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, the default value is set as a string, and your conditions use a `==` equality operator so strings should match, but the type for the `resReturn` property needs to match that of the values in the radio button's `value` attribute and the `checked` attribute condition is comparing string types.

When the bound property `queueManageBean.resReturn` changes, and the `checked` attribute evaluates to `true`, the corresponding radio button will be selected.

In the TS code, you can set the default to a value as shown:

```
queueManageBean = new queueManageBean();
resReturn: number = 100;

constructor() {
  this.queueManageBean = new queueManageBean();
  this.queueManageBean.resReturn = this.resReturn.toString();
}
```

Define your class as shown to hold the `resReturn` property:

```
export class queueManageBean {
    resReturn: string;
}
```

The above will set the default to 100 for the radio button.

Comment: Hey Andrew! Thanks for the help. Ultimately, your response helped me find the solution. Additionally, I needed to change 'value' to '[value]' in my html file. I believe this syntax coordinates with ngModel. After these changes, I get the solution I was expecting.